# Angular, validate form when submitting from outside form

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have a button outside of my form that is submitting a form for me. I would like to get the validation working with it (if at all possible). Just a note - I cannot change the html. Here is the code.

**HTML**:

```
  <form name="newCourse" ng-submit="newCourseForm.saveCourse()">
       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
       <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault">Course Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="courseName" placeholder="Course Name" required ng-model="courseName">
       </div>
       ...
  </form>
```

and then this button is a bunch of divs **above** the previous html

```
  <button ng-click="newCourseForm.saveCourse()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Save</button>
```

The submit button outside the form works, but it does not run the validation like if i had the button inside the form. I am kind of stuck because of how the ui dev built this and am wondering if there is a way around this, or perhaps I missed something. Thanks!

**Edit**:  I have considered wrapping the entire html in a form, and infact tried playing with this. It works however every other button when click tries to submit the form, so maybe if there were a way of preventing that effectively it would work.

Comment: If you add `type="button"` to buttons and inputs form won't be submitted on click. However you mentioned that you can't change html...

Comment: @KirillSlatin I may look into just talking to the designer and doing it this way, as it would make things much easier. thanks!